# Where did blender generate the system-info.txt file?

Tags: filesystem, files, search, blender

Today I launched Blender and asked it to generate system info as I was curious what this button what do:

[image]

And after pressing that this came up:

[image]

I also got this in Terminal:

```
Info: System information generated in 'system-info.txt'
```

However, after searching through my entire computer with the search feature (including hidden files in the search), and looking in predictable places such as `/tmp` and `~/`, I can't seem to find it anywhere... So that is really my question, where has this file been generated?

**Information Update:**

Also, this may, or may not, be relevant, but upon every startup of Blender I get this error message in Terminal:

```
connect failed: No such file or directory
```

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
blender:
  Installed: 2.72.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Candidate: 2.72.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Version table:
 *** 2.72.b+dfsg0-3build1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not concern Ubuntu but rather blender, however I still have an answer for you.

Blender has its own text editor which you can open by selecting text editor from the current editor button.

[image]

After you are in the text editor simply select the browse text button (icon that looks like a notepad) and select `system-info.txt`.

Comment: Firstly, anything which runs on Ubuntu is on-topic here, secondly, so does this file actually exist in my actual file system then? Or is it only accessible through Blender?

Comment: On my blender 2.69 install it shows as 'text: internal'. I think it is only accessible outside blender if you 'Text' > 'Save' in the text editor.

Comment: i am pretty sure that the text file isn't accessible outside blender since i searched with various commands for it and couldn't find it.(you did the same)

Comment: It is block of text that only exists within blender. When you are viewing it in blenders text editor you can save it to an external file `Text->Save As`.